# DRI driver version mismatch

Tags: drivers, apt, 22.04, opengl, mesa

I'm on HP Elitebook 8470p, with an AMD Radeon 7750M GPU, and I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. I'm trying to get an OSG (OpenSceneGraph) based game to work, but it gives the following error:

```sh
libGL error: DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.3.0-devel' vs '23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2')
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

In fact, part of the GL / MESA libs is `23.3.0`:

```
~$ apt list --installed | grep 23.3.0

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 i386  [Installiert,automatisch]
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 i386  [Installiert,automatisch]
libgbm1-amdgpu/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libgbm1-amdgpu/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 i386  [Installiert,automatisch]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dev/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 amd64  [installiert]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 amd64  [installiert]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 i386  [Installiert,automatisch]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 amd64  [installiert]
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 i386  [Installiert,automatisch]
libglapi-amdgpu-mesa/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libglapi-amdgpu-mesa/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 i386  [Installiert,automatisch]
libxatracker2-amdgpu/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
libxatracker2-amdgpu/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 i386  [Installiert,automatisch]
mesa-amdgpu-common-dev/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 amd64  [installiert]
mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 i386  [Installiert,automatisch]
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers/jammy,now 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 i386  [Installiert,automatisch]
```

and the other part has version `23.2.1`:

```sh
~$ apt list --installed | grep 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libegl-mesa0/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64  [installiert]
libegl-mesa0/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 i386  [installiert]
libgbm1/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64  [installiert]
libgbm1/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 i386  [installiert]
libgl1-mesa-dev/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64  [installiert]
libgl1-mesa-dri/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64  [installiert]
libgl1-mesa-dri/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 i386  [installiert]
libglapi-mesa/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64  [installiert]
libglapi-mesa/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 i386  [installiert]
libgles2-mesa-dev/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64  [installiert]
libglx-mesa0/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64  [installiert]
libglx-mesa0/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 i386  [installiert]
libxatracker2/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64  [installiert]
mesa-va-drivers/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64  [installiert]
mesa-vdpau-drivers/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64  [installiert]
mesa-vdpau-drivers/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 i386  [installiert]
mesa-vulkan-drivers/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64  [installiert]
mesa-vulkan-drivers/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 i386  [installiert]
```

Tried installing a version matching the other part's version for both version parts, but there are none:

```sh
~$ apt show -a libegl-mesa0 | grep Version

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Version: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
Version: 22.0.1-1ubuntu2
```

```sh
~$ apt show -a libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers | grep Version

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Version: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
```

What can I do ?

EDIT: Here is the output of `dpkg -l | grep mesa | awk '{print $2}' | xargs apt-cache policy` as requested:

```
libegl-mesa0:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libegl-mesa0:i386:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dev:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libgl1-mesa-dev:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libgl1-mesa-dri:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
libgl1-mesa-glx:
  Installiert:           23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
  Installationskandidat: 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libglapi-mesa:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libglapi-mesa:i386:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
libgles2-mesa-dev:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libglu1-mesa:
  Installiert:           9.0.2-1
  Installationskandidat: 9.0.2-1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 9.0.2-1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libglu1-mesa-dev:
  Installiert:           9.0.2-1
  Installationskandidat: 9.0.2-1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 9.0.2-1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libglx-mesa0:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libglx-mesa0:i386:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
mesa-amdgpu-common-dev:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386:
  Installiert:           1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Installationskandidat: 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:23.3.0.60002-1718217.22.04 600
        600 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
mesa-utils:
  Installiert:           8.4.0-1ubuntu1
  Installationskandidat: 8.4.0-1ubuntu1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 8.4.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
mesa-utils-bin:
  Installiert:           8.4.0-1ubuntu1
  Installationskandidat: 8.4.0-1ubuntu1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 8.4.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
mesa-va-drivers:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
mesa-vdpau-drivers:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
mesa-vulkan-drivers:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386:
  Installiert:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Foreign packages sources?  `dpkg -l | grep mesa | awk '{print $2}' | xargs apt-cache policy` please.

Comment: @nobody added the output to the question - I see some of the packages are from repo.radeon.com - that's because I tried to install the proprietary AMDGPU drivers - should I remove that repo ? But then, how to install these proprietary drivers ?

Comment: @nobody So I disabled the radeon ppas and it appears to be working now. Still, I'd like to have the proprietary drivers …

Comment: @TheEagle Is there a reason you need the proprietary drivers though? If not, and if the ones you're using work fine, then use the one that works better. Run `lspci -v | grep -A10 VGA  | grep Kernel` and it should say that `amdgpu` is in use. If it says that `radeon` is in use *and* both radeon and amdgpu are listed on the modules line, then you should open another question about how to switch from radeon to amdgpu which should be pretty easy if your card is supported.

Comment: @mchid It doesn't say anything about in-use, it only outputs `Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu`. That's literally all it outputs. So, which driver is in use now ? None at all ? :rofl: But yeah, I think I need the proprietary 'cause the AMD Radeon HD 7750M seems to be pretty powerful (score is 5 times that of an Nvidia GPU I have), yet right now the game is unusable on the AMD laptop while it runs (albeit at a low FPS) on the NVidia laptop

Comment: @TheEagle `lsmod | grep "radeon\|amdgpu"` should list which ones are loaded.

Comment: @mchid that gives `amdgpu, amddrm_ttm_helper, amdttm, amdxcp, amddrm_buddy , amd_sched, amdkcl` - so that means I already have the prop. drivers ?